# Resultant of linear combinations of Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, na.numerical-analysis, resultants

The Chebyshev polynomial $U_n(x)$ of the second kind is characterized by
$$
U_n(\cos\theta)=\frac{\sin(n+1)\theta}{\sin(\theta)}.
$$
It seems that
$$\operatorname*{Res}_x \left( U_n(x)+tU_{n-1}(x),\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}U_k(x) \right) =(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} t^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor}2^{n(n-1)},$$
where Res denotes the resultant of two polynomials.

I do not know how to prove this "equality". Is it a known result?
Similar results appeared in Dilcher and Stolarsky [1] theorem 2 and in Jacobs, Rayes and Trevisan [2].

**References**

[1] Karl Dilcher and Kenneth Stolarsky, "[Resultants and discriminants of Chebyshev and related polynomials](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-04-03687-6)", Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 357, pp. 965-981 (2004), [MR2110427](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2110427), [Zbl 1067.12001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1067.12001).

[2] David P. Jacobs and Mohamed O. Rayes and Vilmar Trevisan, "
[The resultant of Chebyshev polynomials](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/D3FA1C0EBDAB83534C86375A0D711BF7/S0008439500017677a.pdf/the-resultant-of-chebyshev-polynomials.pdf)",
Canadian Mathematical Bulletin 54, No. 2, 288-296 (2011), [MR2884245](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR2884245), [Zbl 1272.12006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1272.12006).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $U_n + t U_{n-1}$ is of degree $n$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} U_k$ is of degree $n-1$ with leading coefficient $2^{n-1}$, the resultant factors as
$$ 2^{n(n-1)} (-1)^{n(n-1)} \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (U_n(x_j) + t U_{n-1}(x_j))$$
where $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$ are the zeroes of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} U_k$.

Fortunately, these zeroes can be located explicitly using the usual trigonometric addition and subtraction identities. Telescoping the trig identity $\sin k \theta = -\frac{\cos\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \theta - \cos\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right) \theta}{2 \sin \frac{\theta}{2} }$ we conclude that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} U_k(\cos \theta) = -\frac{\cos\left(\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \theta\right) - \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{2 \sin \theta \sin \frac{\theta}{2}} = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{n}{2} \theta\right) \sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2} \theta\right)}{2 \cos \frac{\theta}{2} \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}}$$
and so the $n-1 = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor$ zeroes of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} U_k$ take the form $\cos( \frac{2\pi j}{n+1} )$ for $1 \leq j < (n+1)/2$ and $\cos( \frac{2\pi j}{n} )$ for $1 \leq j < n/2$.

Since the first class $\cos( \frac{2\pi j}{n+1} )$ of zeroes are also zeroes of $U_n$, and the second class $\cos( \frac{2\pi j}{n} )$ are zeroes of $U_{n-1}$, the resultant therefore simplifies to
$$ 2^{n(n-1)} (-1)^{n(n-1)} t^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}
\prod_{1 \leq j < \frac{n+1}{2}} U_{n-1}\left( \cos\left( \frac{2\pi j}{n+1} \right) \right)
\prod_{1 \leq j < \frac{n}{2}} U_{n}\left( \cos\left( \frac{2\pi j}{n} \right) \right).$$
But
$$ U_{n-1}\left( \cos\left( \frac{2\pi j}{n+1} \right) \right) = \left. \sin\left(n\frac{2\pi j}{n+1}\right) \right/ \sin\left(\frac{2\pi j}{n+1}\right) = -1$$
and similarly
$$ U_{n}\left( \cos\left( \frac{2\pi j}{n} \right) \right) = \left. \sin\left((n+1)\frac{2\pi j}{n}\right) \right/ \sin\left(\frac{2\pi j}{n}\right) = +1$$
and the claim then follows after counting up the signs.

Comment: pleas how you got this :$ U_{n-1}( \cos( \frac{2\pi j}{n+1} ) ) = \sin(n\frac{2\pi j}{n+1}) / \sin(\frac{2\pi j}{n+1}) = (-1)^{j+1}$ ? is that for $ n\to \infty $

Comment: Thank you  for your beautiful and clear proof.

Comment: Signs corrected (the point is that $\sin(x)$ is $2\pi$-periodic and odd).

Comment: @rafik.  the first equality follows from the definition of U_{n-1}.the second equality seems not correct. I think the result is -1.

Comment: I wonder whether you prefer the typography of the first line below to the second or you simply don't consider this sort of thing worthy of attention or what?
$$
\begin{align}
& U_{n}( \cos( \frac{2\pi j}{n} ) ) = \sin((n+1)\frac{2\pi j}{n}) / \sin(\frac{2\pi j}{n}) = +1 \\ {} \\
& U_n \left( \cos\left( \frac{2\pi j}{n} \right) \right) = \left.\sin\left((n+1)\frac{2\pi j}{n}\right) \right/ \sin\left(\frac{2\pi j}{n}\right) = +1 \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: "and so the $n-1 = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor$ zeroes of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} U_k$ take the form $\cos( \frac{2\pi j}{n+1} )$ for $1 \leq j < (n+1)/2$ and $\cos( \frac{2\pi j}{n} )$ for $1 \leq j < n/2$": This is very nice, but shouldn't this just mean that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} U_k$ factors into two smaller Chebyshevs?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Sort of.  From the usual trig addition formulae one gets $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} U_k(\cos \theta) = U_n(\cos \frac{\theta}{2}) U_{n-1}(\cos \frac{\theta}{2}) / 2 \cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy OK, I let LaTeX do its thing with the parentheses.

Comment: @darijgrinberg (This identity, by the way, is a close cousin of the standard fact that the Fejer kernel is the average of Dirichlet kernels.  Indeed I was led to this argument by inspecting the Fourier transform of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} U_k$ and observing its resemblance to the (Fourier transform of the) Fejer kernel.)

Comment: @TerryTao  I've now edited your answer by adding the part about the slashes.